# IE 11 background-position not rendered properly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, browser

When I load my responsive website, my background appears to be in the wrong place, and when I resized the browser a long horizontal bar appeared with nothing but white space. The site works perfectly in other browsers.

I have attached the Respond.JS for Internet Explorer 6,7, and 8. I have attached a reset stylesheet (normalize.css v3.0.2) and I've made sure my CSS stylesheets are before my scripts. Is anyone familiar with some common bugs in Internet Explorer 11 or perhaps a certain stylesheet/JS file to fix it up?

CSS

```
body {
background-image:url(../links/BG.jpg); 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: center 55%;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently IE 11 does not like percentages. Once I changed my CSS to:

background-position: center 175px;

It worked like a charm!